# How to add Sitefinity Nuget Package in package resources in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I want to install Nuget Sitefinity packages in Visual Studio 2012.
For that I require to add package resource.

project>>Manage Nuget Packages>> Settings>> Package Manager>> Package Sources.

I added Name as "Sitefinity Nuget Package" and Source as "https://www.nuget.sitefinity.com/ (tried .org also) It shows "The remote name could not be resolved : www.nuget.sitefinity.org/"

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The correct URL is this: http://nuget.sitefinity.com/nuget

No www in front.